# Use css ::before to place blurred circle behind image

Tags: css

How do I get the black circles (shadows) behind the images?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96L728kn/)

I am using `background` with image sprites to position round button images on span tags. I wish to put a shadow behind each image for visual effect, but cannot position the black dots ***behind*** the button images.

Although it works if I reverse things and put the black dot on the span tag and the button pic on the image tag, *there are many of these buttons and the black dots all appear at once, and after several seconds the button images all appear at once on top of the dots. Works, but looks like crap.*

So, I need a solution that keeps the button images on the span tags, and somehow positions a blurry black circle (shadow) behind the span tag background image.

Here is what I have tried (note the disabled attempt to use `::before` pseudo-class.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="TabMenu">
    <span id="sml_1"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
    <span id="sml_2"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
    <span id="sml_3"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
    <span id="sml_4"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
    <span id="sml_5"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
    <span id="sml_6"><img class="smallIconSprite" src="blank.png" width="40" height="40" /></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{width:800px;height:620px;padding-left:108px;margin-left:-400px;}
.container{background-image:url(background.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.TabMenu{position:absolute;left:0;top:50px;z-index:1;}
.TabMenu{width:200px;height:700px;margin-left:320px;margin-top:55px;}

.TabMenu span{display:inline-block;height:35px;width:31px;margin:1px 7px;padding:5px 0px 0px 10px;}
.TabMenu span{background-image:url(button_icons.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;}
.TabMenu span:hover{opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer;}

xxx.TabMenu span::after{width:46px;height:46px;content:url(blackdot.png);position:relative;top:-55px;left:-18px;}

.smallIconSprite{position:relative;top:-10px;left:-15px;width:45px;height:45px;}
.smallIconSprite{background-image:url(blackdot.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-5px -5px;}

#sml_1{background-position:0px 0px;}
#sml_2{background-position:-40px 0px;}
#sml_3{background-position:-80px 0px;}
#sml_4{background-position:0px -40px;}
#sml_5{background-position:-40px -40px;}
#sml_6{background-position:-80px -40px;}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a CSS shadow?

Comment: I'd be happy to use any method that puts a circle shadow behind the images. The only catch is that I must keep the `span` tags as they are, because there is complicated javascript that requires the current `div`-`span`-`img` layout. *The img tag must be present, but need not be the source of the shadow. I am open to any solution for putting a black shadow behind each image.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest fix: 
Use `z-index: -1;` on the images. That will position them behind the icons. So add

```
img.smallIconSprite { z-index: -1; }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/96L728kn/12/).

But I think, it's nicer to not have the img tags at all. After all, they are only for the background and don't have any semantic value in the document. Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div class="TabMenu">
    <span id="sml_1"></span>
    <span id="sml_2"></span>
    <span id="sml_3"></span>
    <span id="sml_4"></span>
    ....
```

Instead of setting the image on the span, and the background in the img tag, you can use the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for both. This way, you can set the images in `after`, the background in `before`, and the image will automatically be on top. The span itself is only used for positioning and (in this case) doesn't have any visible characteristics.

By using pseudo elements, you don't even need the img tag at all, which is good, since it is only for shadow and doesn't add semantic value to the document.

You can use `absolute` position for the before and after elements, as long as you add `position: relative` to the span.

In this scenario I still used your shadow image, but you could try to use CSS shadows as well. Also, you may add the shadow to the button image as a sprite so you have only one background image.

```css
.container{
    width:800px;height:620px;padding-left:108px;margin-left:-400px;
    background-image: url(http://goodwinstudio.com/_dev/images/bg_filmprojects.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.TabMenu{position:absolute;left:0;top:50px;z-index:1;}
.TabMenu{width:200px;height:700px;margin-left:320px;margin-top:55px;}

/* Position the buttons */
.TabMenu span{
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    margin:7px 7px;
    position: relative;
}
/* Images are positioned at 0,0 inside the span */
.TabMenu span:after{
    content: ""; 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%; /* Or just 40px */
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(http://goodwinstudio.com/_dev/img/btns5.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.TabMenu span:hover:after{opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer;}

/* Shadow image has a slightly negative offset */
.TabMenu span::before{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: url(http://goodwinstudio.com/_dev/images/bgactive2.png);
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
    left:-6px;
}


#sml_1:after{background-position:0px 0px;}
#sml_2:after{background-position:-40px 0px;}
#sml_3:after{background-position:-80px 0px;}
#sml_4:after{background-position:0px -40px;}
#sml_5:after{background-position:-40px -40px;}
#sml_6:after{background-position:-80px -40px;}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="TabMenu">
    <span id="sml_1"></span>
    <span id="sml_2"></span>
    <span id="sml_3"></span>
    <span id="sml_4"></span>
    <span id="sml_5"></span>
    <span id="sml_6"></span>
</div>
<button>Toggle Black Dot</button>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/96L728kn/6/)

Comment: Thanks tons. I was struggling to understand how to use the ::before and ::after

Answer (score 1):

Z-Index is your friend.

`.smallIconSprite{
      z-index:-1;
      position:relative;
      top:-10px;
      left:-15px;
      width:45px;
      height:45px;
    }`